# Use local directory for wrapper in Snakemake rule

Tags: python, snakemake

I want to know how to use a local directory for wrapper in Snakemake rule.

I have read this [Use Github URL for wrapper in Snakemake rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54769322/use-github-url-for-wrapper-in-snakemake-rule) and try follows command

```
rule index:
    wrapper:
        "/public/home/bio/index"
```

But, I get a stderr with `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (slightly hidden) mentioned in the [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/modularization.html#wrappers).

For an absolute path:

```
rule index:
    wrapper:
        "file://public/home/bio/index"
```

Or for a relative path:

```
rule index:
    wrapper:
        "file:public/home/bio/index"
```